# Move reputation gained from questions that are moved to other sub-sites

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

I recently saw [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310672/remove-my-own-question) question which was moved from the SO main site to the meta but noticed that he had retained the reputation that he gained from upvote(s) garnered from the main site.

Although the problem at hand is probably more to do with users not recognising that it should be a Meta question rather than a main site question before deciding to upvote, we should probably have in place a system that removes reputation from upvotes if a question is moved.

This would probably apply to any question. Say it belonged in the Programmers Stack Exchange, but was upvoted on Stack Overflow, and it was indeed moved to where it belonged, any reputation on the asker's Stack Overflow profile in regards to the question that was moved should be moved over to his Programmers exchange profile (if applicable). Obviously this would only apply if the upvoter also owned profiles in those exchange sites.

This begs another question of what system should be in place for moved questions if users did not have other exchange profiles. I think that if a question is moved, the owner of the question should be automatically made an exchange profile for the subsite that the question was moved to. Reputation gained from the upvoted question would only be transferred to the other profile if the upvoter already owned a profile there. Otherwise, just remove the reputation altogether.

Since the example posted involves a question moved to Meta (where reputation is null), the reputation gained from that question should be removed altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any rep gained is just temporary.

Migrated questions get automatically deleted from the source site after some period (I think 30 days) and the effects of any reputation gained or lost by that question will be removed then (as normal for deleted posts).

Comment: Upvotes (hence associated rep) is also moved with the post.

Comment: Note that this happens without regard for the usual rule that rep gained from posts over a score of 3 and at least 60 days old is retained when the post is deleted.